# Powershell: Export-ModuleMember with alias; set Scope

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a Powershell module (.psm1 and .psd1) with several functions and aliases in it.

I added aliases like this:

```
function MyFunction {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        A Method.
    .DESCRIPTION
        Method does something.
    #>
    [Alias("MyAlias")]
    param(
        [String][Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $ParamOne,
        [String][Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] $ParamTwo
    )
    # Do Something
}
```

Later I export the function and the alias like this:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function MyFunction  -Alias MyAlias
```

After importing the module (`Import-Module (Join-Path $env:MODULE_PATH 'MyModule') -Force`), I am able to call `MyFunction` but I can't call `MyAlias`, as it is not found.

In the psd1-File I exported all aliases like this `AliasesToExport = '*'` or this `AliasesToExport = @('MyAlias')`. I still can't call `MyAlias`.

---

However it works, when I remove the Alias-Annotation from the function and export the function and alias like this:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function MyFunction
New-Alias -Name MyAlias -Value MyFunction -Scope 'Global' -Force
```

It only works, when the Scope is set to Global. So my conclusion is that the Export-ModuleMember has a *lower* scope for aliases.

I think that the initial version has worked before, probably with an earlier version of powershell (but I'm not sure about that...).

---

Now my question: Can I set the scope for exporting aliases with `Export-ModuleMember`, or can I set the scope probably in my psd1 file?
Or do I have to change all my `Export-ModuleMembers` and add `New-Alias` calls everywhere (There are quite a lot).

Comment: Is `[Alias('MyFunction')]` the only thing you have at the top of the function definition block? Usually you'd apply it to the `param` block, eg `function MyFunction{[CmdletBinding()][Alias('MyAlias')]param() <# do something #> }`

Comment: There are functions without parameters, and some with. I added a function above